# Getting Attendance record using SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Im trying to create a sql to generate an attendance report to determine the no of absents, late, incomplete login and undertime. Below are my dummy tables used.

```
 Employee 

    Employee ID        Name
      001                Paul  
      002                Juan  
      003                Elise   

 Schedule 

    ID EmployeeID   Schedule 
    1     001       11:00PM - 8:00AM   
    2     002       11:00PM - 8:00AM  
    3     003       11:00PM - 8:00AM


    Attendance  

    ID  EmployeeID    Type       Datetime     
    1     001          0          2015-07-25 22:00:00
    2     002          0          2015-07-25 22:48:00
    3     003          0          2015-07-25 20:48:00  
    1     001          1          2015-07-25 08:00:00 
    2     002          1          2015-07-25 08:44:00
    3     003          1          2015-07-25 08:00:00
```

My sql

```
SELECT * FROM Employee 
INNER JOIN Schedule ON Employee.EmployeeID = Schedule.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN Attendance ON Employee.EmployeeID = Attendance.EmployeeID 
CASE WHEN Schedule.Schedule < Attendance.DateTime THEN 1 as Late;
```

This is my sql, but Im not sure if it is correct. From that it will add 1 to late. I used type column to determine the login and logout where in 1 is logout and 0 is login. Also How can we get the total late with define date eg.,2015-07-20 until 2015-07-25. Any help?

Comment: Is this mysql or sqlserver? They are not the same thing.

Comment: I don't think your query would give you any result. I think you would need to seperate the schedule into a StartTime and EndTime so that you can check the range properly. Also the Select * would go away, instead do EmployeeID , SUM(Case statement)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of a guess here because there is nothing to work with. I would recommend that you not get in the habit of changing column names for a given piece of information in different tables. EmployeeID should ALWAYS be EmployeeID.

Something like this should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
select e.EmployeeID
    , e.Name
    , SUM(Case when s.Schedule < a.DateTime THEN 1 else 0 end) as TotalLate
    , SUM(case when a.DateTime is null then 1 else 0 end) as TotalAbsent
from Employee e
join Schedule s on s.EmployeeID = e.ID
left join Attendance a on a.EmployeeID = e.ID and a.ID = s.ID
```